# Is it possible to interrupt and cancel a build when a file is saved or key typed?

Tags: eclipse

Frequently, I'll make changes in an editor, then save and repeat this process. The build automatically flag in Eclipse starts to create a build as soon as I save. But, I'll make another change and then save again and the current build becomes invalid.

Is there a way to cancel a current build automatically when I start typing into an editor or when I save?

Answer (score 1):

Automatically? No, there's just the Progress View and its ability to send a cancel request. Builds are triggered headlessly in all cases other than when you trigger it from the menu, which is only even available when it's not set to build automatically, and there's no UI dedicated for canceling them.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing when I need to. I'll cancel the build, which will save the file and then build will start over again.